# GDPR ext: Data Policy .pdf file can not be previewed or downloaded

Tags: pdf, gdpr

We have a CiviCRM 5.2.1 on Wordpress 4.9.6 with GDPR ext. 2.6

When we attach a Policy/Terms .pdf file, it seems to be attached, it is uploaded in https://xxx.example.com/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/example.pdf (therefore out of the folder "images") but ... the "Data Policy" link on the Communications preferences page does not work! (it does not open a .pdf preview or not do the download) and redirects to the same page.

We thought that the problem was this: we know that Wordpress does not have a native module of .pdf previw; then we have installed PDF Embedder; it works correctly on the same Wordpress where CiviCRM is installed but only for "normal posts" with .pdf saved on the "normal" Wordpress Media repository.

Please, someone can help us solve this problem? request obviously also addressed to friends of Veda Consulting. :)

Comment: Parvez Saleh , are you there?

Comment: You might be better to log it on the GDPR extension issue tracker https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/issues

Comment: Thx Aidan, I do it soon.